# How to show the command that last executed in vim?

Tags: vim, grep

Sometimes when I write a wrong script, I really have no idea why it doesn't have the expected effects. For example, the following script:

```
nnoremap gr :call Look_For_String()<CR><C-L>
function! Look_For_String()
    exe "grep -R " . expand("<cword>") . &dir
endfunction
```

The function is to search the current word under cursor in directory `&dir`, but it doesn't do as expected. So I want to know what command it executed.Is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

What I would do in this case is replacing the `:execute` with `:echomsg`, re-source the script (`:so %`), and re-execute.

For more complex situations, you can set the `'verbose'` option. With a value of `15`, every Ex command is printed. Since the display often interferes with the script's functionality, it's often advisable to redirect the diagnostic output to a file by setting `'verbosefile'`, too.